# Is it appropriate to use "in terms of" instead of "as" here?

Tags: meaning

> Thus far, we have argued that phrases and sentences are built up by
> merging successive pairs of constituents into larger and larger
> structures, and that the resulting structure can be represented **in
> terms of** a labelled tree diagram.

Does 'in terms of' have the same  meaning as 'as'? Is there any nuance?

Comment: The 'nuance' is that the writer is pompous.

Comment: Ouch, @MichaelHarvey, isn’t that a bit judgy? Why attribute to pomposity that which can be adequately accounted for as, say, mere imprecision?